# Onesignal notification template, Tags are not working

Tags: python, onesignal

The same code without the tags (in the payload) succeeds with default template values, when adding the tags the message is getting 200-ok but on the onesignal dashboard - messages -delivery page i see  NO RECIPIENTS status.
what am i doing wrong ?

```
import json
import requests
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic mykey', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'app_id': 'myapp_id',
    'include_player_ids': ['my_player_id'],
    'tags': [{'key': 'full_name', 'relation': '=', 'value': 'MOSHOE'}],
    'template_id': 'my_template id'}
req = requests.post('ONESIGNAL_URL',headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add custom variables to notifications sent from OneSignal. You need to tag user devices first, then use the tag key within the template directly or API call and the OneSignal servers will substitute that tag key with the value you set on each device.

For example, I tagged a user's device with the `sendTag` method with key:value pair "full_name": "Bob Odenkirk"

Within my API call, I want the message to say "Hey Bob Odenkirk, you are awesome!"

Then my contents property within the API call will look like:

`"contents": {"en": "Hey {{ full_name }}, you are awesome!"}`

OneSignal Tagging Guide:https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/add-user-data-tags

OneSignal Tag Substitution Guide: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/personalization

Comment: It is really bad that you cannot use variables. I want to send users a notification when an event happens and it's not possible to include the name of the person who created the event without a variable. Not ok OneSignal.

Answer (score 1):

Which API endpoint are you calling?  I'm assuming https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications.

It looks like the key should be 'tag' not 'tags'.  If the key is wrong you should get a 400 or it should be ignored.

Also, assuming you're using the right tag key, isn't it possible that the tag filters out all possible recipients?  The docs show returning 200 in two cases: 1) invalid player ids and 2) no subscribed players

Not sure if those apply